# Xcode Swift Position moving - Collisions

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have just added collisions and now my "hero" will go to where he is suppose to for a split of a second then teleport all the way to the left of the screen and I can only see about 1/8th of him!
[Here for Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZr9f.png)

Here is my code for adding collisions, this only happens when I set Dynamic to "true" if I set it to false he goes to where he is suppose to be and I can fully see him! But I need Dynamic to be set to true so he can run into the walls I have added to the collisions.

```
    var heroCategory: UInt32 = 1
    var wallCategory: UInt32 = 2

    hero = CSHero()
    hero.position = CGPointMake(70, movingGround.position.y + movingGround.frame.size.height/2 + hero.frame.size.height/2)
    hero.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: hero.size)
    hero.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    hero.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    hero.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = heroCategory
    hero.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = wallCategory
    addChild(hero)

    wallGenerator = CSWallGenerator(color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: view.frame.size)
    wallGenerator.position = view.center
    wallGenerator.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: wallGenerator.size)
    wallGenerator.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    wallGenerator.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = wallCategory
    wallGenerator.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = heroCategory
```

How do I get it so he goes in the position I want him to be when I set Dynamic to true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your wall is your entire view,  how are you making your wall collision box?  You may be kicking your hero outside your screen.

Comment: I believe you mean **this** code? `func generateWall() {
        var scale: CGFloat
        let rand = arc4random_uniform(2)
        if rand == 0 {
            scale = -1.0
        } else {
            scale = 1.0
        }
        
        let wall = CSWall()
        wall.position.x = size.width/2 + wall.size.width/2
        wall.position.y = scale * (kCSGroundHeight/2 + wall.size.height/2)
        addChild(wall)`

Comment: Or this code `let WALL_WIDTH: CGFloat = 30.0
    let WALL_HEIGHT: CGFloat = 50.0
    let WALL_COLOR = UIColor.blackColor()
    
    override init() {
        super.init(texture: nil, color: WALL_COLOR, size: CGSizeMake(WALL_WIDTH, WALL_HEIGHT))
        startMoving()
    }`

Comment: sorry.  it has been a while since I did sprite kit, you had enough info:

`wallGenerator.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect : wallGenerator.frame)` is what you want to be doing, this gives you the edge only.

Comment: Question, I can't seem to get my "hero" to collide with my "wall" is something wrong with the code? :)

Comment: I just pulled up my old code,  for my wall, I did not set collision or contact, for my hero, I did not set up collision for the wall

Comment: This is what I have only for my wall `wallGenerator.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = wallCategory` and for my hero this is what I have `hero.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = heroCategory
        hero.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = heroCategory | wallCategory
        hero.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = wallCategory`

Comment: It's weird, for some reason the ground works as in Him being able to collide with the ground, but can't seem to get him to collide with the walls